# Will deleting emails on the server will also remove them from an IMAP connected client?

Tags: email, imap, gmail

I've set up a few email accounts in a hostgator shared hosting account. The emails are accessed through gmail's IMAP service. The accounts are now over their quota and I want to free some space by deleting emails. Will emails deleted from the server get deleted from the user's gmail account? If so, what's a good solution?

Comment: If you re sure it's IMAP: Yes, they will be deleted

Comment: I am a bit confused.  I am not aware of any feature within Gmail to access an separate IMAP account.  When I look at my gmail settings all I see is an option for POP3.

Comment: @Zoredache, Gmail not only provides IMAP but Google strongly recommend it be used instead of POP3.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers, I know it *provides* IMAP.  But AFAIK, it can't operate as an IMAP client to pull mail from other accounts.  Perhaps I am miss-reading his question, but it sounded like he was using gmail as a client for his hostgator account?

Comment: @Zoredache, either or both of us could be misreading this question.

Answer (score 2):

On IMAP, mails remain on server. Any client essentially behaves as a remote display. So, yes, when you delete mail from IMAP, it will get deleted from server, destroying the mail completely. From your question, if I dont get it wrong, you dont want this to happen. Options that come to mind are:

- You can have your clients have move those mails to a local folder in
  a mail client such as Thunderbird. This will create a local copy of
  the mail and remove it from server, freeing up space.
- You can instead use a mail client and connect using POP3, which will download mails to their local computers, removing them from server.
- You can purchase more space from GMail.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://eit.engineering.wustl.edu/help/email_move.asp